# How to match an even number of 1's and any amount of 0's

Tags: regex

Im having trouble with this regex problem.

Language is {1,0}.

I want strings with an even number of 1's and any amount of 0's.

Sample strings include:

```
110
101
11
0
empty set 
1111
10101010101
```

Comment: @jedema the total number of 1 should be even and any amount of 0 is accepted

Comment: @jedema aduch is correct the number of 1's has to even and any number of 0's is correct. 0 number of 1's is acceptable since 0 is even.

Comment: How about something like  `0*((10*){2})*`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^(0*10*1)*0*$` or `^(?:0*10*1)*0*$` if non-capturing groups are supported by your regex engine.

It could also be further "simplified" to `^((0*1){2})*0*$`, whatever you find to be more readable.

This matches `1`s by pair and pads with any number of zeros as necessary. It does not match if the number of `1`s is odd. It matches the empty line.

It doesn't use anything fancy so it should work in most programming languages.

See it in action on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fZ2mX2/5).

Comment: There're no needs to make `0*` not greedy.

Comment: While this works, the non-greedy `*?` and non-capturing parentheses are not part of POSIX Extended Regular Expression notation and thus are at least somewhat fancy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Modified the answer taking that into account.